# GCM with multiple senders

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

GCM introduces multiple sender functionality, which allows multiple users to send push messages to the same application. Multiple users are given the same registration id.

If the number of multiple users is three - Andy, Bob and Chris - and Andy is blocked by Google from using the GCM service, is the received registration id still valid?

If the received registration id is blocked by Google, are the others (Bog and Chris) also blocked from sending push messages?

How does Google manage and block malicious users?

In addition, I'd like to know how does Google manage registration id.

Comment: I don't think that multiple users are given same registration id. It should be unique for every user.

Comment: [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html) As link says(GCM official site), multiple users share one registration id. So I don't think multiple users have their unique registration ids.

Answer (score 1):

If an application registers for GCM service with multiple senders (i.e. multiple Google API Project Ids), it will receive a single registration Id, which it should send to the servers of all the senders. After the registration all the senders (that were included in the registration request) can send messages to that application using the same registration Id.
I assume that if Google blocks one of the senders, the others can still use that registration Id to send messages. The registration Id is not assigned to the any sender.
It is assigned to a specific application on a specific device.

Comment: Thank you:) By the way, I have a few questions. As you said as above, if the registration id is assigned to a specific application on a specific device, the method how Google block malicious user is based on sender id or API key(or Google account - becasue sender id and API key are mapped to one Google account), right?

Comment: Also one Google account can have several sender id(project id) and API key by creating a new project. So I think Google detects and blocks malicious users by using Google account. Is this right?

Comment: I have no idea. I think it would make sense for them to block the offending API Key. However, a single project can be connected to multiple Google accounts (though only one of them is the owner), so I'm not sure which account they should block in this case. Perhaps they warn the owner of the offending project.

Comment: Oh, I find the team function in Google api console page. When the user adds other people to the project, the user must set the permissions like 'can view, can edit, and Is owner'. If 'Andy' adds 'Bob' to Andy's project, can always Bob use Andy's project id and api key for gcm service? or depending permissions?

Comment: Also if Google blcoks malicious users depending on offending registration ids, I think the other senders who use multiple sender functionality cannot send push messages in case one of the senders is malicious. What do you think?